# Symfony2 personnalisation every attr radio buttons

Tags: symfony, twig

I can not find the opportunity to customize the attributes on radio buttons separately, because I want to insert a title tag and data-toggle="tooltip" to display a tooltip on every radio buttons

```
$builder
        ->add('type', 'choice', array(
            'choices'   => array(
                '0' => 'Demande', // Here personnalise attr
                '1' => 'Recherche', // Here personnalise attr
            ),
            'expanded'  => true,
        ))
```

I tried with the attr option, but it puts on all the radio buttons ... Or should that EVERY radio button is a different attr.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The expanded choice list in Symfony is actually a `form` with children of either type `radio` or type `checkbox` (depending on the `multiple` option being `false` or `true` respectively).

In my opinion, the best way to solve this, is create a custom type, and do your own templating of the type. This usually is the most clear to the fellow developer and is consistent (and much easier than you might think).

The type should look like this:

```
class MyType extends AbstractType()
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'tooltip_choice';
    }


    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'choice';
    }
}
```

Add this class to your service definitions and tag it as a form type (see docs on this).

Now, the form templating layer will search for a block named `tooltip_choice_row` (for the row of the element), `tooltip_choice_widget` for the widget of the element. If you inspect the default form templates, you can easily dissect how the choice list rendering works in the default implementation. You can either copy and paste it to your custom form theming and override.

The downside of this solution is that it costs a little bit more code, but you can much easier extend your types to include the tooltip itself, and pass that as an option to your form type as well.

Another solution would be to override the `radio_widget` and the `checkbox_widget` blocks in your form template, and check if the parent is a `choice` block. You can find out what exact variables you need by dumping the `_context` variable in your template, it shows exactly what values are available for you to check on.